# Sougou Chinese Input loses settings after reboot

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, input-language, chinese, fcitx

I followed some tutorials to install the Sougou Chinese Input using Fcitx on my Ubuntu 16.04 (OS is in English). One of Sougou's default keyboard shortcut is to press shift to switch between Chinese and English. This is very annoying to me, as I tap the shift key often when I write in English.

This option can be easily unchecked in settings. But for some reason all settings in this software get reversed to default after I restart the computer.

Any thoughts?